# Jquery change div position with other div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am looking for a way to move containers to the center, back again when a new election, and additionally change the size.

Does anyone have an approach how to implement this with jquery?

`fadein` and `fadeout` is certainly the wrong approach.

[code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebever/zjy61c9b/1/)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The latter belongs directly into your question; please do not just put links to external platforms.

Comment: If you want to keep the colours as they move to the middle, then you'll need to separate the position and colour styles.   Otherwise, just swap the class (that has the position) of the div you click with slide0.  eg, here's a starter until you update the question: https://jsfiddle.net/u2okh1pc/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, that was the solution. What do you mean by separating the colors?